# $x^2$ vs $x^3$ as example of function with non smooth inverse

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

In [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-homeomorphism-and-a-diffeomorphism-between-manifolds) question concerning the difference between homeomorphisms (continuous bijections with continuous inverses mapping between two spaces) and diffeomorphisms (bijections with smooth inverses mapping between two spaces), multiple answers give $f(x) = x^3$ as an example of a homeomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism.

I see that $f^{-1}(x) = x^{1/3}$ is not smooth at $x=0$. However, why can't we use $g(x) = x^2$ as an example of a homeomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain and codomain are (as in the linked examples) $\Bbb R$, then $f(x)=x^2$ is not a bijection.